# state as a dependency to useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I want to call `useEffect()` whenever a state change occurs in my **index.js** file.

**index.js**

```
export default withAuth(function Home() {

    const [post, setPost] = useState([])

    const getPosts = async () => {
        const data = await instance.get('/post')
        setPost(data.data)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getPosts()
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar currentPage="home" user={getUser()} />
            <div className={styles.home}>
                <div className={styles.content}>
                    {
                        post.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <PostCard key={index} {...item} />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
)
```

When the state `post` changes, `useEffect()` method should be called.
 If I enter **post** as a dependency for useEffect(),  it will be called infinitely.

My requirement is when a user creates new post, `useEffect` should run and fetch posts from the database

Comment: getPosts() triggers sets post to a new value. It's no suprise if you put post as a dependency of useEffect it causes an infinite loop. What you need to do is to check whether is there a new post on database. Maybe you can consider using websocket to notify users of new post. Or an interval to fetch posts on a regular basis.  Comparing posts to themselves makes no sense.

Comment: I meant, when user posts a new content, index.js should be reloaded. Correct me if my logic is wrong. More precisely, if you create a new post in linkedin, that post will come in top. That's what i needed

Comment: you can do `setPosts([...posts, newPost])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need `useEffect` to rerun in this case. I believe there should be a handler somewhere handling the creation of a new post. You call call `getPosts` in that handler when a new post is created. That would be a much better approach in my opinion.

In a scenario where you don't have control of the new post creation process, then you might want to depend on polling to fetch posts at intervals or listen to a web socket event for when a new post is created.

Comment: Code for creating a new post is written in an componet name modalbox.js. Is there any way to trigger getPosts in index.js file when user click post on modalbox.js ?

Comment: Well, yes. One way to tackle this is to pass the `getPosts()` function as a prop to modalbox.js and invoke the function in the post creation handler. Another way is to create a shared state between those components using ReactContext and exposing a consumer hook (e.g usePostContext) which also exposes function to create and fetch posts and read the posts data from a shared state. You could also use state libraries like Redux or React-Query.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another state and toggle it each time you update `post` state:

```js
const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(true)
```

Now each time you update `post` you do also

```js
setTrigger(prev => !prev) // but not from useEffect
```

and finally you include `trigger` instead of `post` in the `useEffect` dependecies

---

a better approach is to fetch data directly from your function handler each time you need to and don't use `useEffect` for that, makes more sense

Comment: Thanks mate, my requirement is when user create a new post, index.js page should be reloaded with new post

Comment: @UnnikrishnanKJ okay, you know better your requirement ^^